# I tried to find word in Mount Anthor but it seems that I have read the word, even though I haven't had that word. Why?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I noticed that I have only one word for ice form.

Arngeir does not show me any more words.

So I look up the web and try to find those words my self.

I went to https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/Ice_Form

It says that the words are in

Frostmere Crypt, Mount Anthor, and Saarthal

Because I already have ice, I supposed the next word, flesh, will be in mount anthor.

I went there but I have read the word. Nothing glowing again.

My understanding maybe wrong here. It seems that each word always show up in a specific location right?

For example, the word for ice form is ice flesh statue.

Given the location is

> Locations: Frostmere Crypt, Mount Anthor, and Saarthal

according to https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/Ice_Form

I would expect the word ice to be in Frostmere Crypt, flesh to be in Mount Anthor, and statue to be in Saarthal right?

I went to mount anthor and I do not see any words.

Here is a screenshot of me in mount anthor. As you can see I do not have the word flesh. Yet I do not see any glowing texts either

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> I would expect the word ice to be in Frostmere Crypt, flesh to be in Mount Anthor, and statue to be in Saarthal right?

That's not correct. The first word you find will always be "Ice", no matter which of the three locations you visit first. Similarly, the second will always be "Flesh", and the third will always be "Statue". You simply learned "Ice" from Mount Anthor, so you need to visit one of the other two locations.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113820/discussion-on-answer-by-wrigglenite-i-tried-to-find-word-in-mount-anthor-but-it).